# Vertical layout lines in aspx file at visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, format

In aspx file at visual studio there are some vertical lines which order code like formating. I mean

```
div
.   <a>
.    .
.    .
.    .
.    </a>
</div>
```

There were some lines which formats the code. I closed these widget mistakely. How can I open these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the Indent Guides plugin? Then you can select to view them again in the following way:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I searched for indent guides. But in edit->advenced there no view indent guide option im my VS 2012

Comment: Indent Guides is an extension you have to download from Tools / Extensions and Updates. I recommend that you download it if you don't have it :) If you don't have the Indent Guides extension installed then you won't see "View Indent Guides" as I showed in the picture above.

Comment: Thx. I installed it and problem fixed :)